# Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy found in modules jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx-2.3.1-runtime and lifecycle-viewmodel-2.5.1-runtime

Tags: android

getting build error

I had also tried with adding

```
android.enableJetifier=true
```

but, still getting error

Answer (score 0):

- Run `gradle dependencies`
- Find `jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx-2.3.1-runtime` is which libraries dependencies
- Exclude it like:

.

```
implementation('...yourlibray...') {
    exclude group: 'androidx.lifecycle', module: 'lifecycle-viewmodel'
}
```

Comment: I am fresher, don't know how to run gradle dependecies

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-gradle-tasks.html